# jQuery.Gantt - how to show popover bubbles above items

Tags: jquery, bar-chart, popover, gantt-chart, bubble-popup

I would like to know how to show popover bubbles above items (when making a hover) in a jQuery.Gantt chart. Popover bubbles are usually shown on the right of items (as it is shown in the screenshot below):

[image]

However, I need it to be shown above the item:

[image]

This is my relevant JavaScript code:

```
$(".gantt").popover({
  selector: ".bar",
  content: "This is a popover content.",
  trigger: "hover"
});
```

Is that doable? If so, how should I change my code? Any idea?